# React: Passing API Data from State in Parent to Child Component to be Mapped out

Tags: reactjs, arrays, json, state, parent-child

I am new to React and every single time I think I understand state, I run into issues, this is one of them.  I have a parent component which is a form that has a child component that is a select.  The parent form calls an API and updates a state object. I am trying to pass that down to the child component and then run the map function to get at the data and populate the select options. The goal is to reuse the child component so I have attempted to make it dynamic by feeding it all the properties it would need, two of those would be the key and the value I want displayed for each option. I am able to pass down all the props for the select except for the state data, the key and the value I want to use.  It is coming back telling me "Uncaught Error: Objects are not valid as a React child" and then lists out the json key/value pairs from the API call. Can someone please explain how I accomplish this and the why behind it. I come from a background in VBA and basic HTML, I am self taught JS and now React so any help is appreciated.

**Parent:** (Note growerSelect is the state object that contains the API return data)

```
<SelectComponent
                  selectedValue={growerValue}
                  setSelectedValue={setGrowerValue}
                  labelName="labelGrowers"
                  registerName="Grower"
                  title="Growers"
                  dataArray={growerSelect}
                  dataKey="companyid"
                  dataField="name"
                />
```

**Child:**

```
import { useFormContext } from "react-hook-form";
import React, { useState } from "react";

export default function SelectComponent({
  selectedValue,
  setSelectedValue,
  labelName,
  registerName,
  title,
  dataArray,
  dataKey,
  dataField,
}) {
  const { register } = useFormContext();

  return (
    <div className="form-group">
      <label htmlFor={labelName} className="form-label mt-4">
        {title}
      </label>

      <select
        {...register(registerName, { required: true })}
        defaultValue={selectedValue}
        onChange={(e) => setSelectedValue(e.target.value)}
        className="form-select"
      >
        {/* <option>Please Select a Grower</option> */}
        {dataArray.map((data) => (
          <option key={data.dataKey} value={data.dataField}>
            {data}.{dataField}
          </option>
        ))}
      </select>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: Your problem is the {data}.{dataField}... What you want is {data.dataField} otherwise you are passing an object (which is where the error is) and undefined (which is irrelevant to the problem you are currently facing). Or perhaps you want data[dataKey]... Which would be more appropriate? I'm confused by your code.

Comment: Hey some tips: firstly Add console logs at the top of every component stating `Component X rendered` or [use this](https://github.com/welldone-software/why-did-you-render), secondly I'd like to see the parent component above that makes the call thus how it sets state, thirdly based on the error and code provided I believe `{data}.{dataField}` should be `{data.dataField}`.

Comment: `{data}.{dataField}` is wrong but I think he meant `data[dataField]` not `data.dataField`. It appears `dataField` is a string that is provided so it needs to access dynamically.

Answer (score -1):

Changing it from {data}.{dataField} to {data[dataField]} did the trick.  I am assuming the reason it works is that since the data returned is json key:value pairs it is being stored in an array so the [] was necessary to read it.

Comment: Ask a new question and link to the current question to provide context. Keep the current solution clean and concise.